# Position Calls Relative to airport

Tags: navigation, radio

Hey I’m a new student pilot to just trying to learn some new things here. I’ve been having trouble in recognizing and communicating my position with cardinal points relative to the airport in uncontrolled airspaces as well as approach control. For example I seem to be disoriented when describing if I’m North, East, South, or West of whatever airport I’m flying into or from: I’m assuming it’s just the way I read the compass or heading indicator. But please let me know!

Comment: I don't think you should be asking here for such vital information and fundamental foundation building. Ask your instructor, ask someone qualified. This site allows for any random joe to mislead you and put you at risk if their actions go unnoticed.

Answer (score 3):

If your nose is pointed exactly at the airport, then your bearing from the airport is 180 degrees off of your heading- just read the opposite side of your heading indicator or add/subtract 180 from the number on your compass and it will tell you which direction from the airport you are.

If you are not directly pointed at the airport, you should first figure out what heading would take you exactly to the airport. If the airport is at your 2 o'clock (that is, 60 degrees to the right) and you are flying a heading of 030, then a heading of 090 would point you directly at the airport. So you are at a bearing of 270 from the airport, due west.

Keep in mind that this is something you can and should figure out before you ever get in the plane! When you plan your route to another airport you should be able to figure out what your position relative to the airport will be as you get close just from your plan.

You should endeavor to have a mental picture of your situation and your position at all times. To some degree this will come with practice. But if you are having difficulty tell your flight instructor so you can work on it together.